# How do I extract a specific name from the filename of word document in a for loop (in python)?

Tags: python, filenames, extract

Below is the for loop that loop the all the word document files. As you can see below, I have already printed the filename to see the output of it.

```
for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
            source_directory = root_dir + '/' + filename
            # The output of filename is shown in the next section.
           -> print(filename)
            arr = mynotes_extractor.get_mynotes(source_directory)
            list2str = str(arr)
            c = cleanString(newstring=list2str)
            new_arr = []
            new_arr += [c]
            text_file = open(output, 'a', encoding='utf-8')
            for item in new_arr:
                text_file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

The below is the output after printing filename:

```
12345_Cat_A_My Notes.docx
6789_Cat_B_My Notes.docx
54321_Cat_A_My Notes.docx
12234_Cat_C_My Notes.docx
86075_Cat_D_My Notes.docx
34324_Cat_E_My Notes.docx
```

I would like to extract only the specific name, which is "My Notes" in all the filenames of word document inside the for loop as shown above.

```
For instance: 
         Before filename of word document extraction: 34324_Cat_E_My Notes.docx
         After filename of word document extraction: My Notes
```

Comment: `filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]` should work. All the filenames are made the same way?

Comment: Yes all the filenames are the same :) @Alexis may I know what the above code is doing :O ??

Comment: it splites the string into a list of string according to the substring in argument. So first you remove the .docx and then the part after the last '-'

Comment: Which code means to remove the .docx and -1 means the last @Alexis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Written in one line tidiness but can be confusing when you are starting out.

```
filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]
```

output: `'My Notes'`

Detailed explanation below:

```
filename = '12345_Cat_A_My Notes.docx'
```

`.split('.')` splits the string at every period

```
>>>['12345_Cat_A_My Notes', 'docx']
```

`[0]` takes the first element of the list

```
>>>'12345_Cat_A_My Notes'
```

`.split('_')` splits this string at each underscore returning

```
>>>['12345', 'Cat', 'A', 'My Notes']
```

`[-1]` Finally, takes the last item in the list with returning

```
>>>'My Notes'
```

Comment: happy to help. if it solves your issue please don't forget to close the question by accepting the answer

Comment: how do I close the question by accepting the answer? Sorry im a beginner in stackoverflow ._. @Alexis

Comment: just to ask again if I code it  this way it is also possible right  print(filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[3])  like i replace -1 to 3 :O @Alexis